# Does firebase cloud messaging allow targeting of push notifications to a specific device/user etc

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I am trying out firebase cloud messaging (React-native-firebase) and it seems that I am only able to push notifications to all android/ios users, not specific users. Is there a way to target a specific user. Like if a user invites another user only send notification to that one specific user?

Comment: FCM does not have its own concept of a "user".  It just knows devices. You will have to associate device tokens to each user account, then send messages to just the devices associated with that user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flow can be this one:

- User allow notifications on their device(s)
- Grab the generated token and store it in the user document inside a tokens array.
- (If the same user connects to your app in another device, add the new token in the tokens array)
- If you want to target a specific user, get his UID and send a notification to their devices.
- You can also subscribe a user to a topic and send a notification to users subscribed to that topic.

Comment: quick question how would i got about getting "his UID"

Answer (score 2):

two way:

## init

- your client-side subscribe the topic.

```
subscribeToTopic("weather")
```

- your client-side report the user property

```
setUserProperty("name","TOM");
```

## Firebase Cloud Message Console

crate a notification item like this way
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The flow can be this as follows:

User allow notifications on their device(s)
Grab the generated token and store it in the user document inside a tokens array.
(If the same user connects to your app in another device, add the new token in the tokens array)
If you want to target a specific user, get his UID and send a notification to their devices.
You can also subscribe a user to a topic and send a notification to users subscribed to that topic.